# jQuery binds event multiple times when I'm loading dynamically, how to avoid?

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic, bind

I load content dynamically, like this:

```
$.post('main/test', data,function(resp){
    $('#container').html(resp);
});
```

The container is just `<div id="container"></div>`

The "main/test" has this script:

```
$('body').on('click','#login-logs',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#login-logs-last').toggle();
  $('#login-logs-details').toggle();
});
```

Now the issue is, I can load this page "main/test" multiple times, and everytime I do, the event is bound again.

So what happens is when I first load it and click on #login-logs, it works like expected (hides #login-logs-last and displays #login-logs-details), however when I load the page again, it does the opposite, the third time it works again, and so on.

**So the question is, how can I make this on('click','#login-logs') event only be bound ONCE, the first time I load the page dynamically... ? Instead of everytime I load the page...**

Why? I want the user to be able to browse different pages back and forth, and that means the "main/test" page will be loaded multiple times..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll remove the previous handler with `off()` before attaching a new one with `on()` :

```
$('body').off('click','#login-logs')
         .on('click','#login-logs',function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $('#login-logs-last, #login-logs-details').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. That being said, I have very many such events so if there exist something that will "off" them all at once instead of adding it to each one it would be great.

Comment: `$('body').off('click')` will probably remove any click handler attached to the body.

Comment: I think its simpler this way:
`$('.edit-btn').off('click').on('click', function () {
    // #code...
});`

Comment: @AbdelalimHassouna - If the OP actually had an element with the `.edit-btn` class, and didn't use delegated events … oh wait, then it's not at all what the question asks for, but it sure seems easier?

Comment: @adeneo but the question had `#login-logs` which is basically the same